# vertical alignment of text in span - text outside span

Tags: html, css

I need to have span with text aligned in the center.
Previously I have used line-height for this purpose, but in this case the text for some items are longer and this doesn't work any more.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jSdu/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a><span>Short</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><span>Why Should I Monitor?</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span {
    background-color: rgba(216, 25, 11, 0.75);
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    width: 135px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: auto 0;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
}
li, a {
    width: 135px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I want to note that span element has value bottom: 14px. THere is also animate effect on this span. when page loads span has value bottom: -70px (container has overlfow: hidden,s o this span is not seen) and then it appears (using .animate) and goes to bottom: 14px. So the sollution should consider this.

I cannot get this animate effect working in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pr5cL/), but it works on my page that is locally created.

```
$("ul li:not(.img_active)").mouseenter(function() {                 
        $(this).find("span").css("bottom","-55px");     
        $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:15},500);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:-70},500);
    });
```

Here is link: http://www.sheerdigitaltest.net/janus/

Comment: so you don't know for sure if the text is 1 or 2 lines, right?
is flexbox an option for you?

Comment: It is nice, but it really doesnt have enough browser supprot for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:1.25;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 135px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}

a {
    background-color: rgba(216, 25, 11, 0.75);
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li, a {
    width: 135px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

span {
  -webkit-animation: slidein 2s ; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    slidein 2s ; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      slidein 2s ; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         slidein 2s ; /* IE 10+ */
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-top: 70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-top: 70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-top: 70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-top: 70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYf8K/2/)

No IE7 or earlier support. Animation support as per comments.

Comment: I do not need such animate effect. I have my own onmouse over etc. using jquery. I just need to style span text.

Comment: Cool. You didn't explain your animation technique. I just provided one possibility. Should be easy for you to adapt this to your jquery approach. It's just tinkering with `margin-top` rather than `bottom`